# R esponse time of application increases in kubernetes when new pod scales up

Tags: java, kubernetes, load-testing, kubernetes-pod, hpa

I came across this issue during load test where we are seeing considerable increase in response time of the application when new pod scale up by Kubernetes HPA. The HPA we have set is for 75% CPU utlization, minimum 3 pods are already running. So for example:

[image]

As you can see the response time increase drastically, the peaks in this image are the time when new pods scale up. Even if the java application takes some time to start and warming up the JVM, the request serve almost reaches to zero for this time.

Any clue of what could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the correct readiness probe for your pod. Seems that the new pod getting status ready before it's ready for serving traffic

Comment: Even if the new pod is not ready to serve the traffic all other pods should be serving the traffic right? i am expecting a dip in rquest serverd as the pods are almost at max CPU (80-90 percent) utlization but not zero request serverd per second.

Comment: If Kubernetes marked a pod as ready, means it added to service and traffic will be spread to this pod as well, but if in fact this pod can't serve traffic - you will get latency or timeoutes